# OpenAPI Generator + SpringFox documenting extra unwanted endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springfox, openapi-generator

I have a project that uses openapi-generator-maven-plugin version 4.0.0 and springfox-swagger2 2.9.2. All java code is generated from this plugin, based on a 3.0.2 openapi yaml file.

My problem is that when I build the springboot project inside a bundled tomcat server, the swagger-ui.html shows an extra generated endpoint echo-api-controller which I did not declare in my yaml:

[image]

I searched for 2 days for version compatibility solution, trying to override the docket in the Application.java, or modifying the yaml file but this extra endpoint won't leave.

EDIT: Code snippets coming soon

Comment: code snippet would always help understand the problem more clearly

Comment: @PratikAmbani i will provide some code snippets to help on the solution within enough time

Comment: downgrading to version 2.7 removed the extra *-api-controller endpoint, but the ui is different now